# Disk drives interface

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

It is often said that the disk drive interface is a bottleneck in data transfer.
Eg. in the case of hard drives, the data is transferred from hard drive buffer to hard drive memory module. And since the hard drive buffer is a cache memory, why is the interface a bottleneck then? I mean, the cache is a type of sram. So the speed of transfer should be high. Why isn't it so?

Comment: Per Wikipedia, the buffer-to-computer SATA rate is 3 Billion (Bee) bits per second. The article continues "This is still comfortably ahead of the disk-to-buffer rate of today's disks."

Comment: Also, many HDDs (and even SSDs!) use DRAM for their large caches, not SRAM.

Comment: Even so, why is a special kind of interface is required like Sata, pata or scsi? why can't we simply read the buffer in the processor's register?

Comment: serial is fast and less wires

Comment: How would you "simply read the buffer in the processor's register" without some way of actually connecting the buffer to the processor (through one of those interfaces)?

Comment: @brhans - its not that far out of the question ... IDE was just a simple extension of the AT bus, its disks effectively were little different to integrated peripherals on the motherboard - the processor could directly access its registers simply by addressing them.

Comment: @Jules - yes, 20 years ago, and even then the drive's cache wasn't memory-mapped into an address space the processor could just read - it required DMA or interrupt-driven streaming from the drive's cache over the interface (ATA/IDE or whatever) and into the processor's RAM.

Comment: "disk drive interface is a bottleneck in data transfer." - is totally wrong. The bottleneck is either in magentic head access to spinning platters, or in flash access time in SSDs

Answer (score 0):

Hard disks and SSDs most commonly use a serial connection these days, but historically used the IDE interface. IDE was basically a simplified version of the ISA bus that early PCs used. In such computers, you could just directly access the device registers as you suggest.  But when PCI came around it was faster, so older IDE drives were too slow for direct access. Later revisions of IDE (or rather ATA as it was renamed) increased the speed (although not the width: PCI was 32 bits wide but ATA stayed at 16 bits), but processor speed kept increasing and neither PCI nor ATA could keep up.

Eventually we switched from ATA's parallel interface to a serial interface. This makes the connection to the processor less direct, but serial interfaces can run much faster, so they are much  closer to running at full speed, but still this introduces latency and is slower than fast RAM.

Old high speed ATA drives often used 70 or 80ns memory, which ran at similar speeds to the bus.  Modern memory is faster, but nowhere near as much faster as the bus is.  I imagine that modern drives have switched from the 16 bit processors they used to use up to wider bus sizes to increase throughput.

Answer (score 0):

> And since the hard drive buffer is a cache memory, why is the
>   interface a bottleneck then?

Buffers add latency (more time per request) because the contents of the buffer/cache need to be checked. So why do we have them? because usually data is linear so odds are when the buffer is checked the next time, it will already be in the buffer and the disk needen't be checked.

The other problem is

> I mean, the cache is a type of sram. So the speed of transfer should
>   be high. Why isn't it so?

If the data is loaded from the buffer/cache then it is fast. This only happens if the data is already there. If the data isn't in the cache, then it goes to the disk and that is slower. If the data is being read continuously, then odds are it's not in the cache as caches are small compared to the disk.